# Почему браузер считает валидным сертификат от другого домена?

Tags: ssl, браузер

Сейчас только обратил внимание, что на сайте ru.stackoverflow.com установлен сертификат *.stackexchange.com -- и вообще-то браузеры должны предупреждать при заходе на сайт о невалидном сертификате.

[image: сайт и сертификат домена]

Тем не менее -- в строке браузера стоит зелёный замок, соединение защищено. Почему так происходит?

Насколько я понимаю -- должно выдаваться сообщение "SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN", типа такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так ведь написано: «Сертификат действителен только для следующих имён...» Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: @alexolut Это другой сертификат, сообщение об ошибке со старого домена меты. А как правильно заметил VTT там ещё есть поле, куда можно кучу альтернативных имён воткнуть. Туда-то я и не заглянул...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А вы загляните в раздел `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name`, в нем как раз перечисляются прочие домены, для которых данный сертификат будет действителен:

> DNS:*.stackexchange.com, DNS:stackoverflow.com, DNS:*.stackoverflow.com, DNS:stackauth.com, DNS:sstatic.net, DNS:*.sstatic.net, DNS:serverfault.com, DNS:*.serverfault.com, DNS:superuser.com, DNS:*.superuser.com, DNS:stackapps.com, DNS:openid.stackauth.com, DNS:stackexchange.com, DNS:*.meta.stackexchange.com, DNS:meta.stackexchange.com, DNS:mathoverflow.net, DNS:*.mathoverflow.net, DNS:askubuntu.com, DNS:*.askubuntu.com, DNS:stacksnippets.net, DNS:*.blogoverflow.com, DNS:blogoverflow.com, DNS:*.meta.stackoverflow.com, DNS:*.stackoverflow.email, DNS:stackoverflow.email

Comment: Так и знал, что магии не бывает (третий закон Кларка). Никогда не заглядывал так далеко на вкладки сертификата.

Comment: @AK Закон был в том смысле, что магию не отличить от достаточно высоко развитой технологии, а не что ее не бывает совсем.